# bdscale::scale_x_bd - how to remove x-axis label as a result of this function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am using `scale_x_bd`to pretty-up my x-axis. However, it generates an annoying "date" label on the axis. How do I get rid of this.

My sample code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(bdscale)


s1_date <- dmy("30/09/2019")
s2_date <- dmy("07/10/2019")


df <- data.frame(date = c(seq(s1_date, s1_date + 4, by = "day"), seq(s2_date, s2_date + 4, by = "day")),
           value = sample(1:25, 10)) 

p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") 


p1 + scale_x_bd(business.dates = df %>% pull(date) %>% 
               unique %>% sort, max.major.breaks = 15) 

#does not work
p1 + scale_x_bd(business.dates = df %>% pull(date) %>% 
                  unique %>% sort, max.major.breaks = 15) +
  xlab("")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it using `theme()`.

```
p1 + 
  scale_x_bd(business.dates = df %>% pull(date) %>% 
                  unique %>% sort, max.major.breaks = 15)  +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```